# How To Detect locking due to multi row updates

Tags: sql-server, locking

Hi we are thinking of moving our updating records operations over from c# to sql, I am afraid of locking problems, how can I detect this problem if it occurs, and if it causes locking, is there any solution other then making small batches

Answer (score 2):

> we are thinking of moving our updating records operations over from c# to sql

Typically the performance benefits of multi-row DML outweigh any increased blocking.  Plus you *should* be using transactions when performing a multi-row update from C#, in which case you'll have similar locking footprint to a server-side multi-row update:  Every row updated will be locked until the transaction commits.

You don't want to monitor locking, you want to monitor *blocking*.  And it's tracked in the [system wait stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [session wait stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and in [query store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) wait stats, and with the good old [Blocked Process Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/blocked-process-report-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15).

See generally from the docs:

[Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)

And from Brent Ozar:

[Locking and Blocking in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/locking-and-blocking-in-sql-server/)

and

[Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of different monitoring tools and queries that actively watch, log, and report blocking issues. The following would be my recommendation of where to start:

1. Adam Machanic's [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) - This will tell you when a query is locked, how long it's been locked for, what is the query blocking it, and other information about why a query is running slowly. (Note I don't know if it's just me, but I get intermittent issues with trying to access that site. [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/107223/0) is an alternative query I built on top of the aforementioned that provides the same information.)
2. Brent Ozar's [sp_Blitz Toolset](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) - There's multiple queries in this toolset for similarly related, but different performance issue monitoring things. Among them, you should be able to get a grasp of any blocking issues.

Any of the aforementioned monitoring queries can be routinely scheduled with a SQL Agent job (among other ways) to continually capture and log performance problems.

David Browne's answer has a list of useful ways to monitor performance as well. Specifically I would look into leveraging the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Wait Stats](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/wait-stats/). Additionally [Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/) and [Erik Darling](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/) have a lot of good blog posts, in general, on database performance analysis and tuning.

My final recommendation, while it isn't a way to directly monitor blocking performance issues, it is a way to be more proactive to prevent them, would be to become intimate with the [**Execution Plan**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/execution-plans?view=sql-server-ver15) that is viewable for the queries you write. [This intro](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-query-execution-plan-beginners-types-options/) and [this RedGate article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) should help you get started. The reason I mention it, is the **execution plan** of a query will tell you upfront of a lot of common potential performance problems with that query. It can be your guiding map to nipping potential performance issues of your queries in the bud before they actually get a chance to become an issue.